# Swift UIAlertController background color

Tags: swift, uialertcontroller

I'm implementing a custom alert where I set a color for the background. The code below works perfectly when I squeeze it in the simulator, but when I test on the iPhone the custom background is superimposed by the pattern as shown below.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Opções", message: "Deseja realmente excluir esse serviço?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
alertController.setValue(NSAttributedString(string: "Opções", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17),NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]), forKey: "attributedTitle")
alertController.setValue(NSAttributedString(string: "Deseja realmente excluir esse serviço?", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17),NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()]), forKey: "attributedMessage")

alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
let backView = alertController.view.subviews.last?.subviews.last
backView?.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
backView?.backgroundColor = corAzul
backView?.alpha = 1.0
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(10, 15, 30, 30))
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "load")
alertController.view.addSubview(imageView)

let Action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Excluir", style: .Default) { (action) in
    Excluir()
}
let Action7 = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancelar", style: .Cancel) { (action) in
    Cancelar()
}
alertController.addAction(Action2)
alertController.addAction(Action7)
viewController.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {}
```

[image]

What can cause this? And how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, I'm not too proud of it, because it's not elegant and out of the ordinary, but it works!
Apparently the number of subviews in iOS before 10 results in 1 when checked with "cont" then either .last or .fist would work, but in iOS 10 that number is different from 1, I could not determine if it would be constant, But I decided to make a "for" to make all the possibilities.

```
alertController.view.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
for i in 0 ..< alertController.view.subviews.count {
    alertController.view.subviews[i].backgroundColor = corAzul
    alertController.view.subviews[i].layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    alertController.view.subviews[i].alpha = 1.0
    for ii in 0 ..< alertController.view.subviews[i].subviews.count {
        alertController.view.subviews[i].subviews[ii].backgroundColor = corAzul
        alertController.view.subviews[i].subviews[ii].layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        alertController.view.subviews[i].subviews[ii].alpha = 1.0
        for iii in 0 ..< alertController.view.subviews[i].subviews[ii].subviews.count {
            alertController.view.subviews[i].subviews[ii].subviews[iii].backgroundColor = corAzul
            alertController.view.subviews[i].subviews[ii].subviews[iii].layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
            alertController.view.subviews[i].subviews[ii].subviews[iii].alpha = 1.0

        }
    }

}
```

I know this is not pretty, but it was the only solution that worked!
If someone finds something more sophisticated, feel free to contribute

Comment: Better, in my opinion, not to use UIAlertController at all. Making your own alert-like presented view controller is easy.

Comment: I've done this for some cases, but I have several applications for action alerts in my project. And it would be difficult to do something completely configurable and replace in any project

Comment: Understood. But customizing a UIAlertController view is unsupported and (as you've seen) fragile.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the background color, try to change `alertController.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.last?.backgroundColor`. But it will still have a white cover. The view hierarchy of `UIAlertViewController` is not that simply. You do not know if it is a layer or a view that influence the color of the cover.
You try to change the backgroundcolor of the `UIAlertController`. But I do not think it is a good idea. We do not know the difference between iOS8 and iOS9 of the `UIAlertController`. Maybe `alertController.view.subviews.first?.subviews.first?.subviews.last?.backgroundColor` works in iOS10 and not works in some previous versions. The API of the thing you want change is not open for us, and it may change optionally. If you want to have a custom `UIAlertViewController`, try to make one totally new.

Comment: @AthilaZuma sry, i mean using `UIViewController` to build your custom alert view controller.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example or a reference to start? @季亨达